# Alignment issue on images over another image when resize the window and also in zoom in and zoom out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: image for development(bg.png)]I get the output as per requirement. but, the layout of the web page got messed up. when the user resize the window or did zoom.
[image: expected output & actual result with default browser 100%]
[image: output when user resize the browser window]

HTML code:

```html
    <div class="infoWrapper">
        <img src="bg.png" />
        <p class="benefitContent">Lorem ipsum de controverys</p>
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.-Zh3w6-FRNIn988Ih9zRcgHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1"
            class="support" />
        <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.-Zh3w6-FRNIn988Ih9zRcgHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1"
            class="sketch" />
    </div>
```

CSS code:

```css
    .infoWrapper {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
      }
      .benefitContent {
        position: absolute;
        top: 35%;
        left: 43%;
        font-weight: bold;
        width: 16%;
        line-height: 31;
      }
      .support {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3%;
        left: 30.7%;
      }
      .sketch {
        position: absolute;
        top: 3%;
        left: 67%;
      }
```

Comment: Share code please?

Comment: @BatLouhan  yes, i shared. i tried with small icon with width and height 45px.